# Запрос к Many-To-Many используя Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Имею такие таблицы созданые через EF[image: ERD]

Первая и последняя таблицы имеют классы

```
 public class Work
 {
    public Work()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<WorkTag>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int WorkID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "The length of the string must be 5 to 50 characters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add the image!")]
    [Display(Name = "Main image")]
    public byte[] MainImage { get; set; }

    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Install instruction")]
    public string InstallInstruction { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WorkTag> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class WorkTag
{
    public WorkTag()
    {
        Works = new HashSet<Work>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Work> Works { get; set; }
}
```

Связывающая таблица создается автоматически, но проблема в том что мне нужно работать с ней.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы погруппировать `WorkTagWorks` по `TagId` и вывести только 5 самых частых записей.

Comment: А какие конкретно записи выводить? Если пять TagId с наибольшим count в своей группе, тогда коллекцию WorkTags можно считать сгруппированной выборкой из WorkTagsWords. Тогда нужный результат выбирается вот так: `context.WorkTags.Select(t => new { TagId = t.TagId, TagName = t.Name, WorksCount = t.Works.Count() }).OrderByDescending(t => t.WorksCount).Take(5)`

Comment: @Uranus Большое спасибо, это то что нужно

Comment: В чем проблема прописать таблицу, которая и будет связывать?

Comment: не ищу легких путей

Comment: @ViktorKozenko, отлично. Тогда как ответ оформлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в таблице WorkTags все значения в колонке TagID уникальны, то и коллекцию WorkTags можно считать сгруппированной выборкой по WorkTagWorks. Таким образом, остается лишь посчитать сколько Works связано с конкретным WorkTag и выбрать те из них, у который больше всего Works.

```
context.WorkTags.Select(t => new { 
  TagId = t.TagId, 
  TagName = t.Name, 
  WorksCount = t.Works.Count() 
}).OrderByDescending(t => t.WorksCount)
.Take(5);
```